# Android GPS location too much disk space

Tags: android, xamarin, gps, xamarin.forms

I'm developing an app with Xamarin.Forms, my app works on Local Network (VPN).

Here is my Dependency Service in .Droid project;

```
using System;
using Android.Content;
using myApp.Droid;
using Android.Locations;
using myApp.DS;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(DS_Location))]
namespace myApp.Droid
{
    public class DS_Location : Java.Lang.Object, DS_Loc, ILocationListener
    {
        LocationManager _locationManager;
        string _locationProvider;

        public void OnProviderDisabled(string provider) { }
        public void OnProviderEnabled(string provider) { }
        public void OnStatusChanged(string provider, Availability status, Android.OS.Bundle extras) { }

        public void OnLocationChanged(Location location)
        {
            if (location != null)
            {
                App.lblLat = location.Latitude.ToString();
                App.lblLat = location.Longitude.ToString();
            };
        }

        public void ObtainMyLocation()
        {
            _locationManager = (LocationManager)Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LocationService);
            _locationProvider = LocationManager.GpsProvider;
            _locationManager.RemoveUpdates(this);
            _locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(_locationProvider, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is OK, the code works fine.
But when the App runs for 5-6 days the free space on the phone is decreasing.
Now disk usage is 4,96 GB. And I can't delete the file because I can't show the data folder of device. (Not rooted)
I release the project and install the APK and show the free space it's decreasing 2 KB in every 2-3 seconds.
When I disable ObtainMyLocation function and install the APK nothing decreasing, and everything is OK.

Our devices are Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime Android 5.1

Comment: use settings>apps> your app>  clear data to regain space from app data. Though you need to fix your code for this issue.

Comment: @SadiqMdAsif the data is 160 KB, cache is 12 KB. 4,96 GB is on Disk usage on Android device space -> used space. I can't show the detail on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem by updating Android 5.1 Security Update. This bug solved by installing this 500MB update.